# How to train for olympiads?

Tags: education

I've been training a lot for mathematical olympiads the past months, and I would like how to go further. Does anyone know interactive websites training your math skills? Or anything else that could train my math skills, but I'd like not just to do exercises from a book...

Comment: i think book is better

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community

Comment: As Paolo Leonetti says, AoPS is great website for training your math skills because it has a forum where you can ask for help and also has a lot of exams from different olympiads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two important websites, apart from those already mentioned:

www.imomath.com

www.awesomemath.com.

Besides also take a look at different links given in AoPS, especially cut-the-knot, brilliant, nrich and individual olympiad sites of different nations. In addition the following books are recommended:

1. IMO Compendium
2. Problem Solving Strategies, by Arthur Engel
3. Mathematical Olympiad Challenges by Titu Andreescu et. al.
4. Mathematical Olympiad Treasures by Titu Andreescu et. al.

Also, keep abreast with previous papers of IMO at www.imo-official.org
and previous papers of national olympiads of different nations. Putnam problems also help a lot in Olympiad preparation at the higher levels. The Kvant Journal,Kömal Journal, American Mathematical Monthly, Crux mathematicorum are some important journals to refer for instructive problems and theory.

Answer (score 2):

"Art  of  problem  solving"  is  another  site.